# I accidentally removed the Google Search Bar how do I get it back?

Tags: google

I have a one plus 3.  It runs Android Oxyget.

Answer (score 0):

Long tap on screen, then choose "Add widget", then find google search widget and place it on screen where you want.

Answer (score 0):

As [Alex.S said above](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/166276/186920), you can re-add the widget. However, if you removed/disabled the app, here are the steps to get it back:

1. Open `Settings`->`Apps`->swipe to `All`
2. Check if the app `Google` is visible in the list (white circle with a G in the middle)
3. If it is, touch it, and hit the Enable button.
4. If it is not, go to the Google Play Store, and reinstall Google by searching for it.